# Is an integrable function always measurable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

There is a theorem in my textbook.

### Theorem $5.1$

Let $f$ be a nonnegative function defined on a measurable set $E$. Then $\int_E f$ exists if and only if $f$ is measurable.

---

### Notation

If $\int_E f$ exists and is finite, then $f$ is said to be integrable and denoted $f \in L(E)$.

---

I can attain the fact from theorem $5.1$ that, for a nonnegative $f$ definied on a measurable set $E$, $f$ is measurable if $f \in L(E)$.

---

Let there be no condition that $f$, defined on a measurable set $E$, is nonnegative. For this case, if $f \in L(E)$, then is $f$ measurable?

1. $f=f^+ - f^-$.
2. $f \in L(E)$ implies that $\int_E ({f^+ - f^-})$ is finite.
3. Since $\int_E f^+ - \int_E f^-$ is finite, both terms should be finite.
4. Thus, $f^+ \in L(E)$ and $f^- \in L(E)$.
5. By the theorem $5.1$, $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable.
6. The linear combination of the finite number of measurable functions is also measurable. Therefore, $f$ is measurable.

---

However, I cannot ensure that it is possible to proceed from the process $2$ to the process $3$.

I know the following theorems

- If $\int_E f$ exists and $c$ is any real constant, then $\int_E (cf)$ exists and $\int_E (cf) = c\int_E f$.
- if $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative and measurable, then $\int_E(f+g)=\int_E f+\int_E g$.
- If $f, g\in L(E)$, then $f+g\in L(E)$ and $\int_E(f+g) = \int_E f + \int_E g$.

Although $f^+$ and $f^-$ are nonnegative, we cannot apply the second theorem since we don't know yet that they are measurable.

Also, since we don't know they are in $L(E)$, we cannot also apply the third theorem.

---

Thus, for any $f$ defined on a measurable set $E$, if $f\in L(E)$, then is $f$ measurable?
If so, please let me know why~. Thank you.

Comment: An integrable function is measurable, because this is part of the definition of integrability, in particular for positive functions. If $f$ is not measurable, $f^+$ or $f^-$ is not measurable, so at least one of the two integrals $\int f^{\pm}$  is not defined hence $\int f$ is not defined, because it is definied only through $\int f^+-\int f^- $ (this difference should also be finite)